# Deploying a Windows virtual machine on OpenShift Online (Starter Plan)

Tags: openshift, virtualization, vps, remote-desktop, openshift-online

I would like to achieve exactly what is on this video of OpenShift: https://youtu.be/Kx110kqoHo0 (*Deploying a Windows virtual machine on OpenShift*). However on the dashboard of my free OpenShift Starter account, I cannot find the sub-menu "***Virtual Machine***" under menu "***Workloads***", like shown in the video.

Can you please share with me some tips on how to run a Windows virtual machine (*or alternatively a Ubuntu*) on my free OpenShift Online environment? (*unfortunately, I am not in the position of upgrading this account to a paid plan at the moment*)

I would really appreciate your kind guidance and thank you very much for valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called [Container-native virtualization (CNV)](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/cnv/cnv-about-cnv.html) and is not available on OpenShift Online at the moment. It is available in OpenShift Container Platform 4.4 as a Tech Preview.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, I see now. I guess I misunderstood the purpose of OpenShift Starter Plan, mainly due to this webpage: https://www.websiteplanet.com/blog/best-free-cloud-hosting-services/ where it says "This Starter plan includes the most powerful virtual cloud instance on this list". In the meantime I learned that in reality, OpenShift Online is a multi-tenant environment without user accessible virtual machines or other cluster administrative aspects. If I want Windows virtualization, I need to deploy a cluster, which is not available on the OpenShift Online.